# Which training courses in Geodetics can you recommend?

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, geodesy, training

Can anyone recommend any training courses in geodesy which would cover the following objectives:

- Case studies on coordinate issues.
- Overview of geodetic datums, coordinate reference systems and transformations.
- Use of Global navigation satellite systems ie. GPS.
- Methods in projection methods and methods in measuring the Earths surface.
- Vertical datums, geoidal models, vertical CRS and their transformations.
- Orthorectification, georeferencing and other data referencing methods.